# Find the address of the sys_call_table without symbols on a modern kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, hook

I'm trying to develop a KLM (kernel loadable module), which hooks syscalls under linux (4.15.0-55-generic x86_64), but my problem is that I can not find the address of sys_call_table (and not of ia32_sys_call_table), I do not want to rely on symbolic techniques with kallsyms_lookup_name

I have already tried with the technique of iterations on a range of addresses but since I do not really know which address to start iterating, I take myself an illegal access, and my KLM crash ..

When to the technique with kallsyms_lookup_name, I refuse to adopt it because it is really not portable ..

---

I've tried this technique but on my kernel she does not work, i've tried this function :

```
int search_sct(void) {

  sys_call_table = (void *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

  if (sys_call_table == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Couldn't look up sys_call_table\n");
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have not the same addresses on /boot/System.map and when i print the address with this function

Comment: What is a "symbolic technique"? `not portable` - this does not make sense, it's kernel. Kernel code itself by itself is portable only to, well, kernel. And kernel interfaces can change internally too. The "portable" part comes to what kernel exposes, ie. POSIX. What's in the kernel, stays in the kernel. I don't see nothing wrong with [kallsyms_lookup_name](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L201), why don't you want to use that function?

Comment: There is no clean mechanism to hook syscalls, so you have to find a hackish solution anyway. One possibility is, to simply take the address of the target syscall, unprotect the memory pages if necessary (platform depending) and insert a `jmp` instruction to the target function. You could also save the bytes, that you have overwritten, to undo this operation on module unloading.

Comment: Does is there a PoC of this technique ?

Comment: @movequ_clevereverse I bet there is, but it is quite straight forward, so there is no real need for a PoC

Comment: You could possibly do something from userspace to patch the live kernel using kpatch, if the kernel supports it.

Comment: Actual live symbol addresses won't match those in /boot/System.map if the kernel is using KASLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clean mechanism to hook syscalls, so you have to find a hackish solution anyway. One possibility is, to simply take the address of the target syscall, unprotect the memory pages if necessary (platform depending) and insert a jmp instruction to the target function. You could also save the bytes, that you have overwritten, to undo this operation on module unloading.